# add a new Fragment to StatePageAdapter by onClick

Tags: android, gallery, fragment, addition, android-fragmentactivity

I have the following Problem..in my app i have an activity which should show every ProfilePictures of the user + an extra Fragment to add a new picture.

Whats working: I have the Fragment activity with the Fragment and the StatePagerAdapter;

The Fragment: 
     public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment{

```
final static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 2;
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
Bitmap profilePic;
ImageView imgView;
UserProfilePub_viewpager actRef;
Bitmap bitmap;
int pos;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

public ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(Bitmap profilePic, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps, int pos){
    this.bitmaps = bitmaps;
    this.profilePic = profilePic;
    this.pos = pos;
    ScreenSlidePageFragment f = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
    bdl.putParcelableArrayList("profilePics", bitmaps);
    bdl.putInt("pos", pos);
    bdl.putParcelable("profilePic", profilePic);
    f.setArguments(bdl);
    return f;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);
    imgView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.up_pub_iv_viewpager);
    if(getArguments().getInt("pos") == 0){
        imgView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) getArguments().getParcelable("profilePic"));
    }else{          
        int position = getArguments().getInt("pos");
        bitmaps = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("profilePics");

        if(bitmaps.get(position) != null)
          imgView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) getArgumentsbitmaps.get(position);

            imgView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                    loadPic(imgView);
                    return false;
                }

            });     
        //}
    }

    return rootView;
}


public void loadPic(ImageView imgView){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}
```

}

So, now, the main UserProfilePic, which gets downloaded before starting the activity, just get shown in the first Fragment, another additional UserProfilePics should be shown in the rest of the fragments..and if the Array with the pics is empty, a last Fragment should be add with the Option to add a new Picture...but thats not important for now...so, now i ahve a Fragment with the Main UserPicture and a Fragment with the posibility to add a new Picture...by OnLongClick the Gallery from the mobile phone gets called and a new Picture can be set.

FragmentActivity + Adapter:

```
 public class UserProfilePub_viewpager extends FragmentActivity {
ArrayList<Bitmap> pics = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
UserProfilePub_viewpager actRef;    
String url="***************************";
Bitmap profilePic;
int pos;

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

ImageView imgView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout_activity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String USID = intent.getExtras().getString("USID");
    profilePic = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("profilePic");
    pics = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("profilePics");

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("USID", USID));


    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), profilePic, pics);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}

public void onBackPressed(){
    if(mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else{
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}

public static class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    ArrayList<Bitmap> pics = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    Bitmap profilePic;
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Bitmap profilePic, ArrayList<Bitmap> pics) {
        super(fm);
        this.pics = pics;
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos){
        return new ScreenSlidePageFragment().newInstance(profilePic, pics, pos);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_profile_pub_viewpager, menu);
    return true;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 2;

    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){

        int vID = data.getExtras().getInt("vID");
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(vID);

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        decodeBitmap decBit = new decodeBitmap(picturePath, imgView);
        decBit.execute();
    }

}


public void savePic(Bitmap bitmap){
    pics.add(bitmap);


}
```

decodeBitmap is an asyncTask, in which the selected Pictures from the Gallery get scalled..there in the onPostExecute method, he calls "savePic"...and in this last method i want to add a new Fragment to the existing ones on the second last place, which should Show the selected Image.
But i have rly no idea, how to add a new Fragment..i tried to use FragmentTransaction, but that doesnt work..i think because im using an Adapter..can anyone help me? at least just a tipp in a direction i should think or something... =(

------ my own answer------

I already tried to update the viewpager via FragmentTransaction..but it doesnt work...i think i have to do it through the Adapter...and i already tried to do it this way...and it also works..but sadly not at all..when i want to get the Picture back, which got selected in the Gallery intent, the pic get decoded by an asynctask, and this calls a method from the Fragment activity to add a new Fragment...the Problem is...when i send the intent and get the pic abck from the intent Gallery...the Fragment activity gets destroyed and recreated...so the asynctask refers to an old/wrong instance of the activity...how can i solve this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set your main layout as a linear layout. It should contains your ViewPager and a FrameLayout which will contain your add new picture fragment.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <FrameLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then when you want to add your fragment :

`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();`